# Adding <meta name="viewport"> with mobile detection

Tags: javascript, mobile, media-queries, meta

As of late, I've seen a few websites which have a statement equivalent to the following in JavaScript / server-side code:

```
if user is on a mobile device
    print '<meta name="viewport" content="scaling stuff">'
```

Is there any advantage to only adding the tag on mobile devices? It seems less reliable due to basing it on the user agent but I'd be interested to hear both sides.

Comment: Might be a useful [reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: Thanks, @aug. I know what the tag does, my question is just concerning it being conditionally added.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` or `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` on every responsive website you do. It doesn't need to be conditionally added, because it has no effect on desktop devices.

**What does it do?**

A  viewport element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.

The width=device-width part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).

(optional) The initial-scale=1.0 part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser. This will prevent the user from zooming in, which is why I tend not to use that part, but could be handy on a mobile app.

**What happens if you don't use the meta viewport tag?**

The mobile device will assume that the website is 980px wide and attempt to zoom the website to fit it on the screen. It will also attempt to resize the text to make it more readable. This could be handy on a non responsive website, but with a responsive a website you want to have full control over how the mobile is going to render your mobile device.

Comment: I understand the use of the tag and use it myself, I'm just more curious as to the reasoning behind conditionally adding it.

Comment: There only reason you would do that is if you wanted a tablet for example to resize the desktop version of the site to fit, rather than showing the responsive version. However I personally don't think that is a very good idea unless no thought has been put in to how the website will look on a tablet and you just need a quick fix to make it work on a tablet. If were only showing the viewport on all mobile devices, then that would be pointless because the viewport meta has no effect on desktops.

Comment: It seems weird because the user agent check included iOS and Android, the main two tablet platforms, so I'm really unsure. I might contact the website's developers directly because it seems the only way I'll get answers.

Comment: It makes no sense to do that in my opinion. It would probably be best to contact the website developer. I would be interested to know what they say.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought - seems even less reliable than using it on all devices due to the variation in user agents. I will do! Thanks for your help.